# Where is "Voice" on New Projects in GarageBand now?

Tags: macos, garageband

In my old GarageBand App under New Projects there was a "Voice" tab.  How do I locate that or is it no longer in the app?

Answer (score 1):

They have taken that option out of the new project area in the latest version. You can use "Songwriter" and delete the drums and guitars, or chose "Empty Project" and add a vocal track.

If you want to get the settings you've used before you can open an old project and use "Save As..." after deleting all the audio (not tracks) to get a blank project with the settings you like.